# matplotlib plots over ssh from a mac server

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, ssh

I'm new to python. I have simulations producing data on a remote mac server, and I connect from my ubuntu via ssh with X11 forwarding (both trusted and untrusted).

When I use IDL I'm able to plot and a window appears. With ipython 5.1 I'm unable to perform even a simple plot. 
I tried every possible backend with matplotlib, but I still obtain the error:

```
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Error>: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Error>: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: Invalid Connection ID 0
    _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
    Sep 21 17:42:53 Euler.local python[99865] <Warning>: Invalid Connection ID 0
    2016-09-21 17:42:53.802 Python[99865:9373620] An uncaught exception was raised
    2016-09-21 17:42:53.802 Python[99865:9373620] Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 281
    2016-09-21 17:42:53.802 Python[99865:9373620] (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9a70b66c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff944bc76e objc_exception_throw + 43
            2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9a70b51d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
            3   AppKit                              0x00007fff994cc59d _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 1417
            4   AppKit                              0x00007fff994ca906 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 1882
            5   AppKit                              0x00007fff994ca009 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 85
            6   AppKit                              0x00007fff994c9f7e -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 27
            7   Tk                                  0x000000010b7c43dd XMapWindow + 134
            8   Tk                                  0x000000010b734a6f Tk_MapWindow + 69
            9   Tk                                  0x000000010b73d522 TkInstallFrameMenu + 271
            10  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6b0a24 TclServiceIdle + 87
            11  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6974bd Tcl_DoOneEvent + 349
            12  Tk                                  0x000000010b7152f5 TkGetDisplayOf + 981
            13  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6292b5 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1896
            14  Tcl                                 0x000000010b629b61 Tcl_EvalObjv + 57
            15  _tkinter.so                         0x000000010b610dab init_tkinter + 7441
            16  Python                              0x0000000105f217c9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14387
            17  Python                              0x0000000105f2460e _PyEval_SliceIndex + 902
            18  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            19  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            20  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            21  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            22  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            23  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            24  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            25  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            26  Python                              0x0000000105ec230a PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
            27  Python                              0x0000000105ea42ac PyObject_Call + 99
            28  Python                              0x0000000105f209ba PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10788
            29  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            30  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            31  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            32  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            33  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            34  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            35  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            36  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            37  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            38  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            39  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            40  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            41  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            42  Python                              0x0000000105f22184 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16878
            43  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            44  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            45  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            46  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            47  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            48  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            49  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            50  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            51  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            52  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            53  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            54  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            55  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            56  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            57  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            58  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            59  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            60  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            61  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            62  Python                              0x0000000105ec230a PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
            63  Python                              0x0000000105ea42ac PyObject_Call + 99
            64  Python                              0x0000000105f209ba PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10788
            65  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            66  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            67  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            68  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            69  Python                              0x0000000105f1d7d7 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
            70  Python                              0x0000000105f3d7bd PyParser_ASTFromFile + 315
            71  Python                              0x0000000105f3d860 PyRun_FileExFlags + 133
            72  Python                              0x0000000105f3d3fd PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 769
            73  Python                              0x0000000105f4eb23 Py_Main + 3051
            74  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff91d765c9 start + 1
            75  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
    )
    2016-09-21 17:42:53.806 Python[99865:9373620] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 281'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
            0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9a70b66c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
            1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff944bc76e objc_exception_throw + 43
            2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9a70b51d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
            3   AppKit                              0x00007fff994cc59d _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 1417
            4   AppKit                              0x00007fff994ca906 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 1882
            5   AppKit                              0x00007fff994ca009 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 85
            6   AppKit                              0x00007fff994c9f7e -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 27
            7   Tk                                  0x000000010b7c43dd XMapWindow + 134
            8   Tk                                  0x000000010b734a6f Tk_MapWindow + 69
            9   Tk                                  0x000000010b73d522 TkInstallFrameMenu + 271
            10  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6b0a24 TclServiceIdle + 87
            11  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6974bd Tcl_DoOneEvent + 349
            12  Tk                                  0x000000010b7152f5 TkGetDisplayOf + 981
            13  Tcl                                 0x000000010b6292b5 Tcl_ListMathFuncs + 1896
            14  Tcl                                 0x000000010b629b61 Tcl_EvalObjv + 57
            15  _tkinter.so                         0x000000010b610dab init_tkinter + 7441
            16  Python                              0x0000000105f217c9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 14387
            17  Python                              0x0000000105f2460e _PyEval_SliceIndex + 902
            18  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            19  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            20  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            21  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            22  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            23  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            24  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            25  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            26  Python                              0x0000000105ec230a PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
            27  Python                              0x0000000105ea42ac PyObject_Call + 99
            28  Python                              0x0000000105f209ba PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10788
            29  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            30  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            31  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            32  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            33  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            34  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            35  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            36  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            37  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            38  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            39  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            40  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            41  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            42  Python                              0x0000000105f22184 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16878
            43  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            44  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            45  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            46  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            47  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            48  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            49  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            50  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            51  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            52  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            53  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            54  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            55  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            56  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            57  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            58  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            59  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            60  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            61  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            62  Python                              0x0000000105ec230a PyFunction_SetClosure + 826
            63  Python                              0x0000000105ea42ac PyObject_Call + 99
            64  Python                              0x0000000105f209ba PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10788
            65  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            66  Python                              0x0000000105f2457d _PyEval_SliceIndex + 757
            67  Python                              0x0000000105f213e3 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13389
            68  Python                              0x0000000105f1dd62 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
            69  Python                              0x0000000105f1d7d7 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
            70  Python                              0x0000000105f3d7bd PyParser_ASTFromFile + 315
            71  Python                              0x0000000105f3d860 PyRun_FileExFlags + 133
            72  Python                              0x0000000105f3d3fd PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 769
            73  Python                              0x0000000105f4eb23 Py_Main + 3051
            74  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff91d765c9 start + 1
            75  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    Abort trap: 6
```

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!